# unable to install liblz4-dev

Tags: package-management, 20.04, rsync

On Ubunbtu 20.04 I'm trying to install rsync, for that I need to install the liblz4-dev package.
When I try with:

```
sudo apt install -y libzlz4-dev
```

I get:

> E: Unable to locate package libzlz4-dev

So I was looking and found the liblz4-dev on:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/liblz4-dev/download

Now when I try to install it with:

```
sudo apt install ./liblz4-dev_0.0_r131-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

I'm getting:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> liblz4-dev : Depends: liblz4-1 (= 0.0~r131-2ubuntu2) but 1.9.2-2 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

I know it's something that has to do with liblz4-1 .... but I don't really understand the problem or how to solve it.

Any idea on where to look?
thanks

Comment: What was wrong with simple `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install rsync` ? Why do you need `liblz4-dev`? Which [version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=rsync) of `rsync` do you really need?

Comment: I just went to the rsync app, installed the tar.gz file and based on the installing way 
I had installed :
sudo apt install -y gcc g++ gawk autoconf automake python3-cmarkgfm
    >     sudo apt install -y acl libacl1-dev
    >     sudo apt install -y attr libattr1-dev
    >     sudo apt install -y libxxhash-dev
    >     sudo apt install -y libzstd-dev
    >     sudo apt install -y libzlz4-dev
    >     sudo apt install -y libssl-dev

Everything was installed perfectly, but not the liblz4-dev. that's why I can't install the 
rsync that way.

Comment: sudo apt-get install rsync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rsync is already the newest version (3.1.3-8).
rsync set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have a few things going on in here so I'll attempt to break them down:

- It looks like you want the package `liblz4-dev` but you're trying to install `libzlz4-dev` (note the extra preceding "z").  If you run `sudo apt install -y liblz4-dev`, you'll be successful.
- You're running Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) but are trying to install the package from Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) which is giving you the unmet dependency errors.  You would want the link https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/liblz4-dev instead.
- Following up on N0rbert's comment, you can just install `rsync` by doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt install rsync` which bypasses all these difficulties all together.

Comment: Thanks !! solved the problem with libzlz4-dev . I can't believe how I missed that. I was just copying without thinking normally.